# there is an issue with NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate that no return

Tags: objective-c, openssl, mutual-authentication

I am using mutual authentication in iOS 10 that with if statement bellow mutual authentication works correctly.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
  if ([protectionSpace authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {

// do something

} else if ([protectionSpace authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate)  {

// Do something

}
}
```

In iOS 10 the response return with

```
 NSURLProtectionSpace* protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace;

NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate
```

And the problem is in iOS 11 the response return:

```
NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
```

How to force it that response return  **NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate** the first tome instead of **NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust**.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer it here after some hours research. 
In iOS 11  **NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust** always arrive first then pass to **NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate** but in iOS 10 it work in opposite.